# How to check inner elements of multiple div tag's

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of 'div' tags like below,

```
  <div id="filtersrow" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:13px">
       <button id="subfilterrow1" type="button" class="subclassrow1 active"></button>
       <button id="subfilterrow2" type="button" class="subclassrow2"></button>
       <button id="subfilterrow3" type="button" class="subclassrow3 active"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="filtercol" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:13px">
        <button id="subcol1" type="button" class="subcol1 active"></button>
        <button id="subcol2" type="button" class="subcol2" style="height:28px;transform:rotate(-90deg);width:25px;"></button>
        <button id="subcol3" type="button" class="subcol3 active"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="morefilter" style="display:inline-block;margin-left:13px">
       <button id="more1" type="button" class="moreclass1"></button>
       <button id="more2" type="button" class="moreclass1 active"></button>
  </div>
```

Three set of 'div' tag's are there in each 'button' tag's are there. My intention is to go through each div and check button tag class has 'active'. If it has active then i want to push that class inside an array. I have tried but couldn't solve this. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: show us what you tried but couldn't solve.

Comment: You just need to use `.each()` with an appropriate selector.

Comment: `$('div button.active')` is already an array-like object, why do you need an array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ids = $("div button.active").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id");
}).get();
alert(ids);
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/00u8z5u5/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var arr = [];
$('div > button.active').each(function (ele) {
    arr.push(ele);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map) to iterate over all `active` classes, split the [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) into an array & strip out the active class:

```
var classes = $("button.active").map(function() {
    // Split the classnames (could use classList if available)
    var split = this.className.split(/\s+/);
    // Remove the active class, we already know it has it
    // Could remove this check too?
    var activeClass = split.indexOf("active");
    if(~activeClass) split.splice(activeClass);
    return split;
}).get();
console.log(classes);
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/0o31cfg8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` for this,

```
var buttons = $("div button.active").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id");
});
console.log(buttons);
```

This code will select all the buttons inside div with the classname `active` and push them into the array.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/369/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var res = [];

$("div button.active").each(function() { 
      var className = $(this).attr("class").split(" ")[0];
       res.push(className);        
});

console.log(res);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/j7usg74f/)